# Gerrit git push origin tips missing change-id

Tags: git, gerrit

I have a problem as follow. I have excute five times `git push origin` but followd with run `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/feature_1.0`, The terminal tips missings change-id

I have tried to fixed the problem

step1: `gitdir=$(git rev-parse --git-dir); scp -O -P 29002 mycount@example.com:hooks/commit-msg ${gitdir}/hooks/`

step2: `git commit --amend`

step3: `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/feature_1.0`

It still error missings change-id

run git log --graph FETCH_HEAD..HEAD,result is the follow picture.

[image]

Hope you can give me some advise, thanks a lot ...

Comment: `chmod a+x ${gitdir}/hooks/commit-msg`

Answer (score 1):

List the new commits and find those without Change-Id in the message.

```
git fetch origin feature_1.0
git log FETCH_HEAD..HEAD
```

As you have downloaded `commit-msg` and run `git commit --amend`, if the head commit still does not have Change-Id, there is something wrong with `commit-msg`. If you have set `core.hookspath` with a path, you need to copy the downloaded `commit-msg` to that path.

If it's a previous commit that does not have Change-Id, a quick solution is to rebase all the new commits and run `git commit --amend --no-edit`, so that `commit-msg` is invoked after every rebased commit to generate Change-Id.

```
git fetch origin feature_1.0
git rebase -i $(git merge-base FETCH_HEAD HEAD) --rebase-merges --exec 'git commit --amend --no-edit'
```

Comment: Thans for your advise. I have download the commit-msg and run `git commit --amend`.
And I run the followd two command as you provided, it still error missing change-id

Comment: @Joe.Herylee By `git log`, can you find out which commits don't have Change-Id? It would be helpful if you could paste the output of `git log FETCH_HEAD..HEAD`.

Comment: @Joe.Herylee And `git log --graph FETCH_HEAD..HEAD` would be better.

Comment: I have update the result in problem description, thanks

Comment: @Joe.Herylee None of them has Change-Id. It seems `commit-msg` doesn't get invoked. Use `ls -alF .git/commit-msg` to check if it's executable. You could also make it executable as @phd suggests in the comment. Use `git config --show-origin core.hookspath` to check if the hook path is not `.git/hooks` or not empty. You could also edit `.git/commit-msg` and add some `echo foo` lines and check if it runs after `git commit --amend`.

Comment: @Joe.Herylee It should be `ls -alF .git/hooks/commit-msg`. If `commit-msg` is not executable after it's downloaded, inform your Gerrit administrator that `commit-msg` on the Gerrit server is not executable.

Comment: I have edit .git/commit-msg and add some echo foo lines and check if it runs after git commit --amend，it doesn't output foo. I’ll contact the administrator to confirm this problem, and thanks a lot for your advise.